# How to debug a program generated by GNU flex?

Tags: c, gdb, flex-lexer

I'm using flex to generate a lexer. And I have successfully used command
`flex scanner.l` to generate a C file named `lex.yy.c` and then compile it to a 
binary file "scanner". I have enabled the `-g` option for gcc.
When I debug this program with gdb, I expect it goes into the `main()` function in `lex.yy.c`, however, it indeed goes into scanner.l. And when I try to step into function `yylex()`, it directly goes to the next line.

My questions are:

1. Why does gdb go into scanner.l instead of `lex.yy.c`?
2. How could I debug this program?
   Any information or explanation is well-appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question following the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask meaning that you might want to add some code, in particular if you tag your question with [c].

Answer (score 2):

> Why does gdb go into scanner.l instead of lex.yy.c?

Because `flex` generates a `#line "scanner.l"` to associate generated code with the original source it was generated from.

You can hand-edit `lex.yy.cc` and remove these `#line` directives, then rebuilt the binary and you'll see `lex.yy.cc`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! And I find that the [-L] option for flex can be useful. :-)